# Nativescript android build error

Tags: nativescript

Today all of a sudden I was unable to build my app for android on {N} 2.0.1

This is the error I get at the end of the process :

```
Execution failed for task ':processF0DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing and than adding the platform solved my issue

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

Comment: This happens occasionally, I also noticed that when updating only some of the npm modules and try to rebuild I need to delete the platforms.